# how are contracts "loaded" with eth?

Tags: solidity, contract-invocation, gas

If we are to consider the following example, how will `Consumer` have money to pay the 800 gas necessary for running `InfoFeed.feed`? By what mechanism is the person calling `Consumer.callFeed()` charged?

```
contract InfoFeed {
  function info() payable returns (uint ret) { return 42; }
}
contract Consumer {
  InfoFeed feed;
  function setFeed(address addr) { feed = InfoFeed(addr); }
  function callFeed() { feed.info.value(10).gas(800)(); }
}
```

Comment: The person calling `callFeed` isn't being charged. The `Customer` contract is paying the ETH out of its own balance, which is likely zero, so the call will fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sender of the original transaction pays for *all* gas. The gas of any internal transaction is paid by them. In this case, whoever called callFeed() (or whoever called something else that called callFeed()) would pay that 800 gas.

Comment: I think the OP is talking about funds sent as value, not gas.

Answer (score 1):

Normally value could be either sent to the Consumer contract in the transaction that calls callFeed() or in a previous transaction to the contract.

However, in this case the Consumer contract doesn't have any functions marked payable, so compiled with a recent version of solc I don't see any way to pay it, except possibly the weird, tricksy methods like setting it as the beneficiary of another contract's suicide or setting the contract address as coinbase and mining a block.

The example probably needs to be updated to include a payable function.